# Ingestion of XMLs stored in Archive through MLCP

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, mlcp

While importing the XML documents stored in archive through MLCP with the following command:

```
mlcp import -mode local -host localhost -input_file_path "D:\xmlworkflow\test" -input_file_type archive -username admin -password admin -port 8000 -database Documents -input_file_pattern ".*/*.zip" -output_uri_prefix "/modules/"
```

I am receiving the following errors:

```
18/08/10 11:09:41 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type: XML 
18/08/10 11:09:41 INFO contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2 
18/08/10 11:09:41 ERROR contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Error getting input splits: 
18/08/10 11:09:41 ERROR contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Not type information in Archive name
```

I am using MarkLogic 8.0-7.1.

Does anyone have any idea about this error?

Comment: The input file type `archive` refers to MLCP archive zip files created with an MLCP archive export. Maybe you mean to use `-input_compressed` instead?

Comment: you tagged this with `marklogic-9` and `marklogic-7`. Which version of MarkLogic are you using?

Comment: Dave, I am using Marklogic 8.0-7.1.

Comment: mlcp import -mode  local -host localhost -input_file_path  "D:\xmlworkflow\test" -input_file_type archive -username admin -password admin -port 8000 -database Documents -input_file_pattern ".*/*.zip" -output_uri_prefix "/modules/"

18/08/10 11:09:41 INFO contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Content type: XML
18/08/10 11:09:41 INFO contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
18/08/10 11:09:41 ERROR contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Error getting input splits:
18/08/10 11:09:41 ERROR contentpump.LocalJobRunner: Not type information in Archive name

Comment: Thanks grtin, I am able to import document using -input_compressed option. Can we also do the filter so that only selected documents will be imported. Archive contains images and pdfs along with XML and I wan to only to ingest XML in marklogic database.

Comment: @grtjn could you add an answer with -input_compressed to make it easier for others to find?

Comment: @dave-cassel: done..

Answer (score 1):

The input file type `archive` refers to MLCP archive zip files created with an MLCP archive export (`-output_type archive`).

I think you meant to use `-input_compressed` instead. Something like:

```
mlcp.bat import -mode local -host localhost -input_file_path "D:\xmlworkflow\test" -input_compressed -username xxx -password yyy -port 8000 -database Documents -input_file_pattern ".*/*.zip" -output_uri_prefix "/modules/"
```

To selectively import specific files, I'd recommend using a transform which passes through `$content` if the file should be ingested, or `()` (empty-sequence) if skipped.

Documentation about MLCP transforms can be found here:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_82518

HTH!